# NullReferenceException on closing datareader

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I am just learning to work with ADO.NET and I seem to have a problem.What I am trying to do is get the data from a table and insert it into a DataTable.Here is my code:

```
public DataTable GetCategories()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = null;
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        DataTable categories = new DataTable();

        try {
            connection = new SqlConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "GetCategories";
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            categories.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            categories.Columns.Add("CategoryName", typeof(int));

            while (reader.Read()) {
                int categoryId = (int)reader["Id"];
                string categoryName = (string)reader["CategoryName"];
                categories.Rows.Add(categoryId , categoryName);
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            DataTable error = new DataTable();
            error.Columns.Add("Error");
            error.Rows.Add(e.Message);
            return error;
        }finally{
            connection.Close();
            reader.Close();
        }
        return categories;
    }
```

Here is my SQL query :

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCategories]
    AS
        SELECT Id , CategoryName
        FROM Categories
```

Where I run this method I get back on reader.Close() an exception that says NullRefferenceException.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I just noticed that reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); throws an InvalidOperationException.Is this because of the query?

Comment: Does your code get to the line reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();? It seems as if either connection or reader is never instantiated due to an exception.

Comment: try stepping thru the code using the debugger.. pay attention to the first line in the While Loop you are probably getting an error at cmd.Execute these 2 lines need to be changed `categories.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            categories.Columns.Add("CategoryName", typeof(int));` you want to change them to `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@CatagoryName,categoryName);` 
`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@Id,categoryId);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SqlCommand` needs access to the `SqlConnection` object. E.g.:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetCategories", connection)
```

Also, have a look at the [using block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/yh598w02.aspx) - it's a better way to structure your data access code.

Answer (score 7):

The way you have your code written means that if there's an error creating or connecting to the `SqlConnection`, your finally block will try to close a `reader` that hasn't been set yet.

Either check for a null value in the finally block or re-structure your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the `null` reference in you `finally` block:

```
    finally{
        connection.Close();
        if (reader != null)
          reader.Close();
    }
```

If your `SqlConnection` throws an exception when `connection.Open()`, the reader is not initialized and its value is `null`, so you need to check it in your `finally` block.